# Navigation drop down menu stuck to the left of links

Tags: drop-down-menu, navigation

Trying to make a drop down on a nav like this:
[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdvC8.png)

Here's the HTML and CSS - it just stays to the left of the nav links

```
 <header>
        <img src="logo.png" alt="" class="logo">
        <nav class="right">
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Food</a></li>
                  <ul> 
                     *4 <li> items*
                  </ul> 
                <li><a href="#">Housing</a></li>
                   <ul>
                     *4 <li> items*
                   </ul> 
                <li><a href="#">Cleaning</a></li>
                   <ul>
                     *4 <li> items*
                   </ul> 
                <li><a href="#">Decor</a></li>
                   <ul>
                     *4 <li> items*
                   </ul> 
            </ul>
        </nav>
 </header>
```

```
header, ul, a{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #6B8E23;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding-right: 50px;
    font-weight: 600;
}


header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}


.right a{
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    border-right: 2px solid white;
    font-size: large;
}

.right > a:last-of-type{
    border-right: none;
}

.nav.links a:hover{
    background-color: #000;
}

.nav-links ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}

.nav-links:hover > ul{ 
    display: block;
    border: none;
}
```

[Here's what it's doing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ps1mb.png)

The drop-down sticks to the left of the navigation links, and doesn't actually "drop down" below the original headings. How can this be fixed?